# Java date with different formats

Tags: java, date

Hey Im using the code below to parse dates in different formats.

The trubel is, it takes the first format and parses the date even if it doesn't fit.

```
public static Date parseDate(String date) {
    date = date.replaceAll("[-,.;:_/&()+*# ']", "-");
    System.out.print(date);
    List<String> formatStrings = Arrays.asList("d-M-y","y-M-d");
    for (String formatString : formatStrings) {
        try {
            System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat(formatString).parse(date));
            return new SimpleDateFormat(formatString).parse(date);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Console:

```
1994-02-13
Wed Jul 18 00:00:00 CEST 2018
```

OR

```
13-02-1994
Sun Feb 13 00:00:00 CET 1994
```

So I don't get why does the first format allways parse?

Comment: Because you're parsing the string. Not formatting it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simpler example in jshell. the "d-M-y" does parse both because it defaults to lenient. If you do `setLenient(false)` it will exception on the date in the other format.

```
|  Welcome to JShell -- Version 9.0.1
|  For an introduction type: /help intro

jshell> java.text.SimpleDateFormat dmy = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("d-M-y");
dmy ==> java.text.SimpleDateFormat@596ca10

jshell> dmy.parse("13-02-1994")
$2 ==> Sun Feb 13 00:00:00 CST 1994

jshell> dmy.parse("1994-02-13")
$3 ==> Wed Jul 18 00:00:00 CDT 2018

jshell> dmy.isLenient()
$4 ==> true

jshell> dmy.setLenient(false)

jshell> dmy.parse("1994-02-13")
|  java.text.ParseException thrown: Unparseable date: "1994-02-13"
|        at DateFormat.parse (DateFormat.java:388)
|        at (#6:1)
```

FYI, the Java 8+ API way to do this:

```
jshell> java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter dmy = java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy");
dmy ==> Value(DayOfMonth,2)'-'Value(MonthOfYear,2)'-'Value(YearOfEra,4,19,EXCEEDS_PAD)

jshell> java.time.LocalDate.parse("13-02-1994", dmy)
$2 ==> 1994-02-13

jshell> java.time.LocalDate.parse("1994-02-13", dmy)
|  java.time.format.DateTimeParseException thrown: Text '1994-02-13' could not be parsed at index 2
|        at DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0 (DateTimeFormatter.java:1988)
|        at DateTimeFormatter.parse (DateTimeFormatter.java:1890)
|        at LocalDate.parse (LocalDate.java:428)
|        at (#3:1)
```

Comment: Tank you thats a pretty nice answer :)

Comment: I certainly recommend the Java 8 way. Thank you for supplying this.

Answer (score 2):

your loop stops at the very first `return`statement, remove the return statement from your loop, then it will lopp all over your date formats.

EDIT : as requested in the comments:

```
  public static Date parseDate(String date) {
    Date dateToReturn = null;
    date = date.replaceAll("[,\\.;:_/&\\(\\)\\+\\*# ']", "-");
    String formatString = "d-M-y";
    if (date.matches("\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}")) {
        formatString = "y-M-d";
    }
    try {
        dateToReturn = new SimpleDateFormat(formatString).parse(date);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("the given date does not math this format " + formatString);
    }
    return dateToReturn;
}
```

Here above I considered you only have two possible formats.

Comment: I want to return a Date, but it should do the return if there is an exception?

Comment: okay, but based on which format ? , because having two formats confused me

Comment: well I use this in a web backend and I could be given in different formats from the browser

Comment: I edited the answer, I hope it helps